# Swiftmailer: dbReplacements by user id?

Tags: php, mysql, email, smtp, swiftmailer

The Swiftmailer docs says you can create your own class to handle replacements using the Decorator plugin:

```
class DbReplacements implements Swift_Plugins_Decorator_Replacements {
  public function getReplacementsFor($address) {
    $sql = sprintf(
      "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = '%s'",
      mysql_real_escape_string($address)
    );

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      return array(
        '{username}'=>$row['username'],
        '{password}'=>$row['password']
      );
    }
  }
}
```

But in my case my database contains duplicated email address, i.e. the same address can appear on 3-4 accounts, so I need to get the replacements based on the user id instead.

How do I modify the above class to match my criteria?

Comment: How do you pass the email adresses to the to address when you create the mailings?

Comment: Like this: http://swiftmailer.org/docs/plugins.html#providing-your-own-replacements-lookup-for-the-decorator
`$decorator = new Swift_Plugins_DecoratorPlugin(new DbReplacements());
$mailer->registerPlugin($decorator);`

Comment: I didn't mean the decorating ;) I meant when you create the emails. You set the to address, the text of the mail body and so on. There is one place where the addresses come in to be decorated *later*.

Comment: Ahh sorry :) Like the docs says: `$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Wonderful Subject')
      ->setFrom(array('john@doe.com' => 'John Doe'))
      ->setTo(array('email@domain.com' => "Email Domain"))
      ->setBody('Hi {firstname} {lastname}!<br />Your birthdate is on {birthdate}.');`

Comment: Well, that contains only a single email address which not even comes from the database. It is unlikely you know at that place the ID of the email in the database. As it is already unknown at that point you can *never* know it later on. So your problem is already up higher. Check your data-processing, you will at least need the ID at some point earlier before doing the replacements. Locating that point is crucial to make you a suggestion how to extend the plugin providing the ID for your replacements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `swiftmailer` don't know anything about id, you have to translate email to id by yourself. For example add new property to `DbReplacements` holding an associative array `'email' => 'id'` (of course firstly limited to known ID, ie. `SELECT email, id FROM user WHERE id IN(1,3,6,77)` ) and in `getReplacementsFor` simply use email as index in this array to get user id.

Code sample to make it more clear:

```
class DbReplacements implements Swift_Plugins_Decorator_Replacements {
  public $email2id = array();
  public function getReplacementsFor($address) {
    $sql = sprintf(
      "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = %d", $this->email2id[$address]
    );

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      return array(
        '{username}'=>$row['username'],
        '{password}'=>$row['password']
      );
    }
  }
}

$dbReplacer = new DbReplacements();
$decorator = new Swift_Plugins_DecoratorPlugin($dbReplacer); 
$mailer->registerPlugin($decorator);

$users = array(
    array('email'=>'john.doe@example.com', 'id' => 16),
    array('email'=>'john.doe2@example.com', 'id' => 13),
);

foreach ($users as $user) {
  $message->addTo($user['email']);
  $dbReplacer->email2id[$user['email']] = $user['id'];
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how.. Since I've got the same email address on multiple users, it would only overwrite any existing keys in the array?

Comment: But you know to which ID you want send email? So what is the problem to construct such array, by selecting email  &id from DB?

Comment: Yes I know which user id to send to. But in your example the email address is the array key, and keys in an array must be unique, so how does that solve my problem?

Comment: By selecting emails only for given IDs to this array.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfect! Would still be nice to get the solution below to work as well though.. :)

Comment: This works perfect! BUT I've got a bit problems now. I've added a feature to test send an email before sending the real newsletter. I'm assigning a user to the function above, and add a different e-mail address as "setTo". The problem is that the function above are looking for the address in "setTo", not for the user I'm assigning to $email2id. Why is that!? The point is to send a parsed/decorated email to a different address.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I modify the above class to match my criteria?

You can't. The ID is missing. Unless you don't have the ID at least associated with the message in question (that is the message of the event that is happening behind the scenes), you won't be able to create a concrete subtype of `Class Swift_Plugins_DecoratorPlugin` offering it's own `_Replacements` interface providing the message when asking for replacements.

Let's create your own plugin that still is a decorator plugin for the replacements:

```
<?php

interface My_Swift_Plugins_Decorator_Replacements extends Swift_Plugins_Decorator_Replacements
{
    public function setMessage(Swift_Mime_Message $message);
}

class My_Swift_Plugins_DecoratorPlugin extends Swift_Plugins_DecoratorPlugin implements My_Swift_Plugins_Decorator_Replacements
{

    private $_replacements;

    public function __construct(My_Swift_Plugins_Decorator_Replacements $replacements) {
        $this->_replacements = $replacements;
    }

    /**
     * Invoked immediately before the Message is sent.
     *
     * @param Swift_Events_SendEvent $evt
     */
    public function beforeSendPerformed(Swift_Events_SendEvent $evt) {
        $this->setMessage($evt->getMessage());
        parent::beforeSendPerformed($evt);
    }

    public function setMessage(Swift_Mime_Message $message) {
        $this->_replacements->setMessage($message);
    }
}
```

If you assign the ID to the message in your plugin you would get the message set *before* the `getReplacementsFor` is called. You could then assign it to a property and read it out in that function.

```
class DbReplacements implements My_Swift_Plugins_Decorator_Replacements {
  private $message;
  public function setMessage(Swift_Mime_Message $message) {
      $this->message = $message;
  }

  public function getReplacementsFor($address) {
    $sql = sprintf(
      "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = '%s' and id = '%d'",
      mysql_real_escape_string($address),
      $this->message->emailID;
    );

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      return array(
        '{username}'=>$row['username'],
        '{password}'=>$row['password']
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The code above looks great! But how do I assign the ID? I'm using a "regular" select query and will built my recipients array in a regular while-loop. I've managed to run your code, I'm receiving the email, but the tokens aren't replaced, since I don't know how to set the `$this->message->emailID`

Comment: But are you able to change anything in message while it is sending? Recipients are added before sending occurs, and then every ID set to message will be overwritten.

Comment: @Webkungen: Please add the code how you loop create the emails to your question. I already asked for this, I have no clue what is so hard to add it ;) That code is necessary to find a good point to inject the ID to messages. My answer only shows how it is possible to access the message object when the replacements are to be provided. It's done with the hope to add additional data to each messsage that then could be accessed inside the replacement routine.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller: That's the missing link I still have, too. My answer just shows how to extend the plugin with more functionality. In the hope to access meta-data provided with the message(s).

Comment: Sorry! I would do it just like the docs say `$Users = array();
 $query = "SELECT "
   ."user_id, user_email "
   ."FROM `table` "
   ."ORDER BY RAND() "
   ."LIMIT 2";
 
 foreach($dbh->query($query) as $res){
  $Users[] = array(
   "Id" => $res['user_id'],
   "Email" => $res['user_email'],
  );
 }`

And then just a foreach-loop on `$Users` to trigger `$mailer->Send()`